# c++ new instance in function

Tags: c++, class, pointers, instance

I have this problem:

```
void myFunc()
{
  MyClass * myInstance = NULL;

  newInstance(myInstance);
}

void newInstance(MyClass * instance)
{
  instance = new MyClass(...);
}
```

the code seems to work fine, but when I exits from newInstance function, my myInstance is null and not with the values that have inside newInstance... where is the problem?t

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The pointer is copied into `newInstance` and then you change the value of that copy. If you want to modify the pointer inside the function, you need to pass it by reference:

```
void newInstance(MyClass*& instance)
{
  instance = new MyClass(...);
}
```

Or alternatively, you could pass a `MyClass**` and do `*instance = new Class(...);`.

Either way, it would be preferable to actually return the pointer instead of passing it as a modifiable argument.

```
void myFunc()
{
  MyClass * myInstance = newInstance();
  delete myInstance;
}

MyClass* newInstance()
{
  return new MyClass(...);
}
```

Of course, you will have to remember to `delete` the object. To avoid this, you can make it safer by using smart pointers:

```
void myFunc()
{
  auto myInstance = newInstance();
}

std::unique_ptr<MyClass> newInstance()
{
  return std::unique_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass(...));
}
```

Comment: Or even better let newInstance return the pointer. Just be careful of memory leaks

Comment: thanks, I can't return, 'cause I have more than one parameter like 'instance'

Comment: @ghiboz In which case, the function is doing too much.  You also have the possibility of returning a `struct` with more than one pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to pass a refetence to a pointer, or return the pointer from the function:

```
void newInstance(MyClass*& instance)
{
  instance = new MyClass(...);
}

MyClass* newInstance()
{
  return new MyClass(...);
}
```

But you don't want to deal with raw pointers to dynamically allocated memory. What you really need is to use [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) here, particularly [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).